# Изменение шаблонов не меняет витрину

Tags: cms, tpl, prestashop

Хочу разобраться с шаблонами *prestashop 1.6*. В `presta.loc\themes\default-bootstrap` лежат `tpl`, я так понимаю, это и есть шаблон.

Если так, то почему, например, после очищения/дописывания файла *header.tpl* или *footer.tpl*, витрина не меняется?

Comment: кеш не пробовали чистить?